# formatting wildcard match in a variable for find

Tags: bash, find

Im using find along with arrays to build the command so allow differing patterns in a function. So Im placing -name and the pattern in an array. One pattern has a space in it and Im struggling to work out how this should be formatted to the find command recognises it:

This is the pattern:

```
   name_opts=( -name "* "  )
   find  $HOME  "${name_opts[@]}"
```

I thought about escaping the space with a backslash but that didn't work.Also tried escaping the double speech marks. This looks ok on Echo but Find doesnt recognise the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`"* "` only matches file names that *end* in space. You want `"* *"` to matches any file name that *contains* a space.

Comment: Thats what I want, Im matching leading and trailing spaces. The issue is put ting that search pattern into an array variable

Comment: You've done that correctly. If you are looking for names with *both* leading *and* trailing whitespace, you want `" * "` as the pattern

Comment: Thanks thats handy to know. The way I have it above doesnt work for me. If I echo out the contents of the array it lists the contents of the current directory which makes sense as its echo * . I think to work the * has to be within speechmarks however I cant get this to work

Comment: It sounds like you are checking with `echo ${name_opts[@]}`, not `echo "${name_opts[@]}"`.

Comment: One quick question, trailing spaces wildcard, doesnt work with files  -name "* " works fine with Directories, Im guessing because of the file extension on the filename, is there a way of formatting the wildcard to get around this?

Comment: figured it out -name "* .*"